Is Cassandra Queuing More Efficient When Queuing by a Single Component of the Compound Partition Key?
I have a problem in Cassandra that I would like to query data by a column that has high cardinality. Now, in order to have a more balanced database, the partition key needs to be chosen in a way that partitions have more equal sizes. But for me, it is valuable to be able to query by a column that has high cardinality on one hand, but on the other hand, store data efficiently between the partitions.
Let's consider the scenario where I want to store alarms for a stock price. I have this table:
CREATE TABLE drop_price_alarm (
        userId bigint,
        symbol text,
        price decimal,
        PRIMARY KEY ((symbol, userId), price)
        );

In my understanding, I would be able to efficiently query all records that have a stock price bigger than some value, and also making the (symbol, userId) as a compound partition key would ensure that the records are distributed reasonably between the partitions. As some popular stocks like Apple will have more records, and still, I have the order preserved by the price, so Cassandra would be able to easily retrieve all alarms bigger than a certain stock price.
The problem comes when I run this in Java; I get this error:
Caused by: org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException: Query; CQL [SELECT * FROM droppricealarm WHERE symbol=? AND price<=?]; Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING

This is my table:
@Table
public class DropPriceAlarm {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(
            name = "symbol", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String symbol;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(
            name = "userId", ordinal = 2, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private long userId;


    @PrimaryKeyColumn(
            name = "price", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private BigDecimal price;

    public DropPriceAlarm(String symbol, long userId, BigDecimal price) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}

And this is my repository:
    List<DropPriceAlarm> findBySymbolAndUserIdAndPriceLessThanEqual(String symbol, long userId, BigDecimal price);
}


Why would i get this error, and what is not correct with my reasoning?

more i read about Cassandra the more i think it is not a good tool to handle this kind of use case. Perhaps Hbase is a better option.

The issue is that the partition key is not being included within the query. The partitioning mechanism does distribute the data to the nodes based on a consistent hash mechanism (murmur3 by default).
To retrieve the data, by default you should be providing the partition key since that is what is required to know where to obtain the data from.
The clustering order, based on price in your example, only orders within a partition, it is not a global sort order of any kind.
Given you wish to retrieve data based on a price, you have three options:

using an SAI index (C* 5.0 / Datastax Astra), but this will be an expensive query since it is a scatter-gather query which can ask every node to retrieve the data and then order on the co-ordinator.
using spark-sql which will parallel query all the token ranges and pull the data to spark to order, this would not be a fast / low-latency operation.
remodel the data to match the query patterns. (not enough information on the patterns is within the question.)


thanks, lets assume two scenarios: '1.  I query by only one part of the partition key example partition key is (symbol, userid) and I query for all the rows that have the a  symbol equal to some value',   '2. I query on a column symbol that is not at all included in the partition key, query is the same as before give me all rows that have value symbol to some value'. Now Im interested is there any difference between the queries, do i need to use the entire partition key or can I provide just one part of it, (the first, in this case) and still have some performance benefits from the query.

Use case: I'm truing to retrieve ordered data from multiple partitions using one query. In my example I store alarm for when a stock value reaches a price. I can partition only buy the stock name and do a query: select by stock name for price bigger than some value. But this has a problem as lot of people will be interested in a small number of famous stocks: apple, tesla, facebook.. this makes some partitions to grow big. So I want to distribute the stocks in different partitions with partition key (symbol, userId) but order this partitions records by price for fast retrieval

You can not query by a fragment of the partition key without it being the same 'ALLOW FILTERING' concept which scans the whole table. The partition key is a single hashed value, you may have multiple fields within it, but they are still hashed to a single value, so supplying a part of the key, gives it no way to get to the hashed value - it needs all of it.
